# In openGL, can I handle window resize without GLUT?

Tags: opengl

I am working on an openGL project. The application should handle window resize events and correctly adjust the aspect ratio accordingly. I've seen many solutions for window resize handling, but they all require GLUT. Is there a way that I can implement the window resize handling without using GLUT?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL does not know anything about windows, it just knows about a *default framebuffer* - sometimes called an *window-system provided framebuffer* or whatever. The default framebuffer can be a window, some output surface or even hardware overlay, or some off-screen resource (like pbuffers or some implementation and/or platform-specific stuff). The connection between an actual windows and a GL context is done via platform-specific GL binding APIs like `egl` (originated for mobile/embedded GLES, but nowadays also applicable for desktop GL), `wgl` (on Windows), `glX` on Unix X11 window system, and so on.

But managing the window is a topic completely outside of the realm of OpenGL.

> Is there a way that I can implement the window resize handling without using GLUT?

Yes, `GLUT` is just a (very outdated!) cross-plattform wrapper around those platform-specifc APIs mentioned before. You can always directly implement all that stuff using the native APIs of your platform. Or you can use some other wrapper API or windowing toolkit with OpenGL support (like `GLFW`, `SDL`, `Qt`, `gtk`, `wxWindows`, whatever).